# passing multiple arguments while execute an exe file in node.js

Tags: node.js

Am using bellow code to pass two arguments along with an exe file execution as follows.But it is not working.in command line it is working properly.

```
var osName =jobData[0].os;
exec('Shedule.exe',['value=Start'],['ID=osName'], function (err, data) {                
                console.log(data);                  
               });


in cmd
C:\Users\Desktop\ver>Shedule.exe value=Start ID=WIN7-64
```

Comment: Did you try `exec('Shedule.exe value=Start ID=osName', function (err, stdout, stderr) {` ? and where is this node app running at?

Comment: `exec('Shedule.exe value=Start ID=osName', function (err, data) {` i tried this way but it is not working

Comment: It could be a path issue as well to the file. What `err` you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.I think this will solve your problem.

```
 var osName =jobData[0].os;
    exec('Shedule.exe',['value=Start','ID='+osName], function (err, data) {                
                    console.log(data);                  
                   });
```

Comment: Thank you it is getting now:-)